# How to send a file from Server to Client in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I am writing a login system in Node.js. I am generating password automatically

```
app.post("/new/user", (req, res,)=>
{
   var passwd = generateRandomPasswd();
   fs.writeFileSync("credentials.txt", "Username : "+req.body.userName+"\nPassword : "+passwd);
})
```

How can I send this credential file to the client machine??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.post("/new/user", (req, res,)=>
{
   var passwd = generateRandomPasswd();
   fs.writeFileSync("credentials.txt", "Username : "+req.body.userName+"\nPassword : "+passwd);

   var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream('credentials.txt');
   readStream.pipe(res);
})
```